# Simple Jframe with a combobox and a textfield and a result in a label

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtextfield, jcombobox

I am a Java newbie so this question maybe foolish for some. I am using Eclipse with the swing window builder, but i can't figure out how to make my Jframe work.

What i want to achieve is rather simple.

1. I want a combobox with a number of options (lateron two columns, but i start with one), representing a bankcode.
2. A textbox for entering a bankaccountnumber.
3. a button that needs to use the selected value from the box and the accountnumber from the textbox to call a method createIban(code,number).
   This method returns a String with the full IBAN.

I want this string presented in a label or something (maybe also copied to the clipboard or some).

I hope someone can help me to get further in this quest.

Comment: And where exactly did you get stuck ? Please post some code showing what you tried and explain what exactly isn't working. Here on SO we are not going to write your code for you, but we are more then happy to help you overcome a specific problem

Comment: Its fairly simple, Try googling for it there is plenty of help out there, Post here when you have got some code and stuck on a particlar part! Here is on [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jba-TQe4h-0) on how to do it, can probably skip first half.

Comment: i googled a lot, but couldn't find an example that is simple enough to work for me. So i'm glad with a simple example as given below. This i can use to get my full version working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you have a code to begin with... but you should check some tutorials and google a little bit to know how to make it prettier.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Test extends JPanel {

    private static JComboBox comboBox;
    private static JTextField textField;

    // Create a form with the fields
    public Test() {
        super(new BorderLayout());
        // Panel for the labels
        JPanel labelPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1)); // 2 rows 1 column
        add(labelPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);

        // Panel for the fields
        JPanel fieldPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1)); // 2 rows 1 column
        add(fieldPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        // Combobox
        JLabel labelCombo = new JLabel("Bank Code");

        // Options in the combobox
        String[] options = { "Option1", "Option2", "Option3", "Option4", "Option15" };
        comboBox = new JComboBox(options);
        comboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // Do something when you select a value

            }
        });

        // Textfield
        JLabel labelTextField = new JLabel("Bank account number");
        textField = new JTextField();

        // Add labels
        labelPanel.add(labelCombo);
        labelPanel.add(labelTextField);

        // Add fields
        fieldPanel.add(comboBox);
        fieldPanel.add(textField);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Test form = new Test();

        // Button submit
        JButton submit = new JButton("Submit Form");
        submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                createIban((String) comboBox.getSelectedItem(), textField.getText());
            }
        });

        // Frame for our test
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Text Form Example");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.getContentPane().add(form, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        // Panel with the button
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.add(submit);
        f.getContentPane().add(p, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        // Show the frame
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static void createIban(String selectedItem, String text) {
        // Do stuff with your data
        System.out.println("Im in createIban with the values: " + selectedItem + " and " + text);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That really gets me started!

Comment: If you are really going to provide sample code, please improve it. Respect the Swing threading rules, get rid of the `JPanel` extension, get rid of the static fields, get rid of the static methods (except the main method)